# Side Effects of Wrong Voltage on Device

Tags: laptop

I have an odd scenario. I had a [5v 22 LED DotStar string](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-dotstar-leds/overview) attached to an [Arduino Leonardo++](http://www.16hertz.com/product/16hertz-leonardo-plus-plus/) connected to my [Acer r3](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/AU/content/model/NX.MP5SA.004) laptop via USB. One of my colleagues attached 12v to the LED string, causing it, the Arduino, and my laptop to stop working. Acer customer support instructed me to insert a small pin in the reset hole in the bottom of the laptop, which allowed it to boot properly, etc. but my internet seems to be running slowly/hanging on all networks. Here's my question:

What other issues/problems might have been created by this?

Answer (score 1):

By using a higher voltage, you probably shocked (at best), eventually damaged some internal chips.

No one else than a qualified technician can tell what has been damaged exactly by this overvoltage by doing some physical and electrical tests, as from 5v to 12v this is almost never not noticeable with eyes only.

If you notice stability or speed problems (freezes, hangs) just after this shock, there is great chances that something has been damaged. In the best scenario, there is an overvoltage protection on your USB ports but you could have placed certain internal components in an unstable state, so I suggest to remove completely the battery and power supply of your laptop during one day or two, in order to empty any residual static electricity, and try again to see if it makes things get better.
In the worst scenario, something has been irredeemably damaged so the only option is to send your laptop back for replacement, but you have to find a valable reason (and believe me, overvoltage is a serious cause to void the warranty).

Anyway, maybe you got a diagnostics CD provided with your laptop. I would run it after this two days break in order to check if something is noticeable by a software diagnostics.

Concerning the Arduino or the LED string, which are a much more simple components, if they stopped working, I would not expect any kind of resurrection.